# Access dynamically created data-attribute in jquery on click event

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to create a module which lets user compare different products, When a user click on add to compare it will append the id of that product in `data-list` attribute of compare box and this part is working fine.

Main problem is when i try to access that data-attribute value from compare box it only returns value from first click.

For eg,suppose user added three products to compare box but and if he click on compare box it will return those 3 products but if he/she tries to remove the selected product `data-attribute` still return those 3 product which were added initially and neither add new product to compare box nor removes any product from compare box.

Here is code :
**HTML**

```
<div class="checkbox-inline col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="margin-left: 10px">
<label><input type="checkbox" class="compare-result" 
id="compare-<?php echo $product_id;?>" value="<?php echo $product_id;?>">
Compare</label>
</div>

<a href="#">
 <div class="compare" id = "compare-box" data-list = "" >
  <div  style="margin-bottom: 5px;padding: 0px;font-size:13px">
   <h4>Compare Results (<span id="compare-items"></span>)</h4>
  </div>
 </div>
</a>
```

**Jquery**

```
var count = 0
var list = $("#compare-box").attr('data-list');
if(list)
{
  list = JSON.parse(list);
}
else
{
  list = [];
}
$(".compare-result").on('click',function(){ 
if($(this).is(":checked"))
{
if(count < 4)
    {
        var id = $(this).val();
        list.push(id);
        count++;        
    }
    else
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('input.compare-result').not(':checked').attr("disabled",true);
        alert('you can only compare 4 product');
    }
}
else
{
    var id = $(this).val();
    count--;
    if(count < 4)
    {
        var index = list.indexOf(id);
        if (index > -1) {
            list.splice(index, 1);
        }
        $('input.compare-result').not(':checked').attr("disabled",false);
    }
    else
    {
        alert('error');
    }   
}
selectedList = JSON.stringify(list);
$("#compare-box").attr('data-list',selectedList);
$("#compare-items").html(count);
console.log(selectedList);
});

//Main Problem
$("#compare-box").on('click',function(){
var data = $("#compare-box").attr('data-list');
console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using data API wrong. `<div data-list="">` only tells browser that this element has pre-defined data API element. Later on any actions will use in-memory data object (that is not visible in DOM representation of element).

To get/set data attributes you must use `$(selector).data('key', valueToSet)`.

So `$("#compare-box").data('list');` and `$("#compare-box").data('list', selectedList);`